# Custom post type and taxonomies structure

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am looking for having custom post types and "categories" (limited, known, and just only one) for post. I want the following URLs:

site.com/cpt   (archive of all the posts inside custom post type)
site.com/cpt/cat1   (archive of all the posts inside custom post type and category cat1)
site.com/cpt/cat2    (archive of all the posts inside custom post type and category cat2)

I know how to achieve the first but not the sencond and third. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So to clarify, you want to use the core `category` taxonomy, or you'll be registering your own for your CPT?

Comment: I don't mind having to register ony taxonomy. Whatever the best approach will be for the situation.

Comment: Well, one involves a lot of convoluted hacking. The other involves registering a custom taxonomy ;)

Comment: I am registering a custom taxonomy but I don't know how to achieve what I've written in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `slug` component of your [`rewrite` argument](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments) for your custom taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy([
    'rewrite' => [
        'with_front' => false,
        'slug'       => 'cpt',
    ],

    // Other args
]);
```

Comment: Doing so if inside my taxonomy I have a "catagory" named cat1, I am not getting the posts with that category in the url 'cpt/cat1'. In fact, I cannot get the posts within the category :(